# display constant footer on mobile devices through media-queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to display fixed footer at the bottom of the screen for mobile browsers. I have tried putting position: fixed in the Footer id. However, it is still not working correctly. How can I set the footer to continuously display as the user scrolls down the page?

```
#footer {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: @Adrift Yes just for the example. Once its working.I will place a advertisement in its place.

Comment: Ok, I will modify it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
#footer {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The 'bottom: 0px' will fix the footer to the bottom of the screen, and the 'width: 100%' will center the footer contents.  You will have to add a background color as well so that your page content does not show through the footer.

Plus, as @Adrift said, remove the extra closing div tag from the footer area.